# How Do I Run ./configure with MinGW?

Tags: mingw, glib

I am looking at this webpage

http://mathieu.carbou.free.fr/wiki/index.php?title=Glib_for_Win32

And it tells me I need to run the following commands.

```
./configure
make
make install
```

How do I actually do this and where can I find these files. I have MinGW and Mysys installed in my C drive.

Comment: configure       
should do it

Comment: yes but where do i say "configure" in windows.

Comment: should work from anywhere as it will be in the path

Comment: So what I wanted to know was that I was supposed to open the bash program, navigate to the folder with the configure file then run the supplied commands. i was using command prompt.

Comment: @LoganMurphy: Any chance you could post what "bash" you used to run this command? I'm having the same issues.

Answer (score 22):

On Windows there is 2 ways to achieve this if you have `MinGW` installed you also have to install `msys` for `MinGW` some `MinGW` installations already come pre-installed with msys to check go to your `MinGW` folder and see if you have a `msys` folder inside there.

Second make sure the path inside the Environment Variables of your windows is setup to `MinGW` and `msys` like so

`C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`

may look different on your system depending where you installed it.

Now you can simply click on `msys.bat` inside `msys\1.0` folder which will open up a shell where you can navigate with `ls` and `dir` but you won't be able to leave the `msys` folder no matter what.

But now you have the ability to run commands like `sh` inside your `Command Prompt` which is all you need.

Click on your Windows Start button -> Run -> cmd.exe

now in Command Prompt just run `sh` command and it should show up as `sh-3.1$`

now you can navigate to your project folder and run the command

```
./configure
make
make install
```

and that should completely build any of your pojects.

Comment: it gives: sh: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: Try "cd c:/users/<usr>/<path_to_lib>" and after that "./configure"

Answer (score 1):

configure is a shell file created by libtool, the code must provide one or generate with autoconf or source can provide a ./autogen.sh script for create the configure, sometimes configure is a perl script. maybe the project use another build tool as CMake or QMake...

Answer (score 0):

I find that the 'configure' file is found in

```
C:\MinGW\share\libtool\libltdl
```

After adding the above path to PATH, I was able to run configure -h. I am very new to this environment so I am not sure it works, but the man page was generated.