# Cannot build Soundpipe DSP library on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, build, mingw

I've found the lightweight DSP c library - [Soundpipe](https://github.com/PaulBatchelor/Soundpipe).
I want to use some filters from it. I do not really need binary files, but the problem is that the repository doesn't have its main header file - `soundpipe.h`. As I understand, this is because the library uses specific modules ported from [Csound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csound) and [FAUST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAUST_(programming_language)) languages. Also the repository's readme doesn't have installation guide for Windows. It says:

> By default, Soundpipe needs `libsndfile`, and a standard build
>   environment. Other modules that use other external libraries will need
>   to be explicitly compiled by modifying `config.mk` (*note: but the Makefile's folder doesn't contain `config.mk`, there is only `config.def.mk`*)
>
> To compile:
>
> `make`
>
> `sudo make install`

Ok, I've downloaded and installed [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/).
Then I have tried to use MSVC's `nmake` - it doesn't work:

```
makefile(7) : fatal error U1036: syntax error : too many names to left of '='
Stop.
```

Here is the beginning of the makefile:

```
> .PHONY: all clean install docs bootstrap
> 
> default: all
> 
> VERSION = 1.5.0
> 
> INTERMEDIATES_PREFIX ?= . PREFIX ?= /usr/local
> ...
```

After that I've downloaded MinGW, `mingw32-make` result:

```
config.mk: No such file or directory
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'config.def.mk', needed by 'config.mk'. Stop.
```

Ok, when I try to run the `configure` command, it doesn't work on my Win7 x 64 (`sh: ./configure: No such file or directory`, etc...)

I have the paths in mt system `path` variable:

```
C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
```

Links that I've read:
[How Do I Run ./configure with MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22873884/4149835)
[Getting mingw-get to install correctly - mingw/msys path missing plus more!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5953307/4149835)

MinGW's `configure` doesn't work after reinstalling Git for Windows and GCC_TDM too (No idea how to run configure).

Any ideas how to build the library or at least find missing source files (or make through CSound, Faust, ...) ?

Answer (score 2):

The Soundpipe build system is designed to be used with POSIX environments, of which there are a few to choose from on Windows.

I've been able to build Soundpipe using both MSYS2 and Windows Bash on Windows 10.